# rubber lengths in coffins and aligning to the bottom baseline of a paragraph

Tags: xcoffins

I want to obtain a certain layout, illustrated below: at some point in a line, I'd like to "switch to paragraph mode" (just like a `parbox` does) and then at some other point I want to resume back to normal full-width typesetting. In my case, the idea is to get a ToC-like look using `dotfill`, but the question stands for regular text too, I suppose.

Using the `xcoffins` package I got this partial solution (MNWE below) which is neither very elegant in terms of code nor correct-looking in terms of result:

[image: result]

My questions (illustrated with arrows in the picture above):

1. Is this the right™ way to do it ?
2. I want the "dot filling" to go all the way to the right margin. Using two `\dotfill` commands somehow works, but the result doesn't look quite right (cf picture, there is extra space between the two dotfills). Is there a way out of this ?
3. How do I fix the wrong interline spacing below the coffin ? In the "central column" I'd like all lines to be equally spread apart.
4. Is there a more elegant way to horizontally join two coffins with adjacent text ? Here I'm joining `bol` and `para` with an explicit `.5ex` spacing and this feels wrong (even though it looks OK).

.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{xcoffins}

\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\cont% full-width container
\NewCoffin\para% multiline paragraph
\NewCoffin\bol % beginning of line 
\NewCoffin\eol % end of line

\SetVerticalCoffin\cont{\linewidth}{~}

\SetHorizontalCoffin\bol{In-coffin beginning of line.}

\SetVerticalCoffin\para{15 em}{Dummy text but long enough to span several lines at the specified width\dotfill}

\JoinCoffins \bol[B,r] \para[T,l](.5ex, 0pt)

\JoinCoffins \cont[B,l] \bol

\SetVerticalCoffin \eol {\CoffinWidth\cont - \CoffinWidth\bol}{\dotfill\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\JoinCoffins \cont[\para-B,\para-r] \eol

A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines. 
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.

\TypesetCoffin\cont

A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines. 
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples. It isn't suitable.

Comment: `B` isn't supposed to exist for horizontal coffins - only vertical ones.

Comment: Though they seem to be defined, even so.

Comment: There is something really weird about this ... :(.

Comment: @cfr: could you comment on why `minimal` is unsuitable for minimal examples ? (real question btw). I'm using `memoir` in real life, and wanted to reduce potential interference. Would `article` have been more "suitable" here ? thanks

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided?s=2|1.9683. `article` would be perfect here. For graphics (e.g. TikZ pictures) `standalone` is a popular option, but for other things, `article` would be recommended. (Unless the issue specifically concerns Memoir or something, obviously, as then you'd need that class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two minor adjustments to your MWE which produce the desired result.

The first adjustment is to nudge the `\eol` coffin a bit to the left when joining it to the `\cont` coffin. `.22em` is one half of the space which `\dotfill` uses for a box containing an individual dot. Tweak this as desired. Although the gap is less visible now, you might need a slightly larger adjustment for a perfect match.

```
\JoinCoffins \cont[\para-B,\para-r] \eol (-.22em,0pt)
```

The second adjustment involves adding `\strut` to the final line of `\para`. I have no idea why this is necessary as I don't know why the use of coffins (either the underlying `expl3` functions or `xcoffins`) loses vertical spacing here.

```
\SetVerticalCoffin\para{15 em}{Dummy text but long enough to span several lines at the specified width \strut\dotfill}
```

Here's the result:

[image: output from modified code]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{xcoffins}

\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\cont% full-width container
\NewCoffin\para% multiline paragraph
\NewCoffin\bol % beginning of line
\NewCoffin\eol % end of line

\SetVerticalCoffin\cont{\linewidth}{~}

\SetHorizontalCoffin\bol{In-coffin beginning of line.}

\SetVerticalCoffin\para{15 em}{Dummy text but long enough to span several lines at the specified width \strut\dotfill}

\JoinCoffins \bol[B,r] \para[T,l](.5ex, 0pt)

\JoinCoffins \cont[B,l] \bol

\SetVerticalCoffin \eol {\CoffinWidth\cont - \CoffinWidth\bol}{\dotfill\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\JoinCoffins \cont[\para-B,\para-r] \eol (-.22em,0pt)

A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.

\TypesetCoffin\cont

A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.


\end{document}
```

Comment: The 0.5ex and -0.22em still need to be adjusted manually when font size varies, but this workaround fixes most of my problems, cheers !

Comment: @Gyom That's true but, at least for the `\dotfill`, I don't see much way around it since the command just prints a series of boxes of width `.44em` with a dot in the middle of each, basically. Probably really you should trace through what happens specifically at the start of `\dotfill`, but I couldn't figure it out and thought a workaround better than nothing at all when nobody else answered in terms of coffins. Perhaps somebody else will see this and post a better solution all round. I hope so!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without coffins:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{almostcenter}
 {\par\nobreak
  \leftskip=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15em)/2\relax
  \rightskip=\leftskip
  \parfillskip=-\rightskip
  \noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\unskip\dotfill\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
\begin{almostcenter}
Dummy text but long enough to span several lines at the specified width
\end{almostcenter}
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.
A long chunk of text to show how the thing flows with surrounding lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the first line of the `Dummy text ...` aligned with the last line preceding it on the baseline?

Comment: @cfr Possibly; that requires the usual tricks with measuring the positions. I don't think one can dispense with them, for this application.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your answer. So much voodoo though. Would you have any suggestions as to where I could learn about these `leftskip`, `dimexpr`, `relax` etc ? Cheers.

Comment: @Gyom Not too much voodoo, actually; `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` is space at the left and right of lines; `\parfillskip` is the space automatically added at paragraph end, by setting it equal to the negative of `\rightskip` we obtain that the leaders are flush with the right margin. For `\dimexpr` search on the site, you'll find many examples.

Comment: Why doesn't the OP's code work?